# How to change text color by hovering on the button in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have 1 red button. I want to change text color on button to blue, when bring mouse pass button or point mouse on button. in canvas

Comment: In the linked dup, just replace drawing rectangle with drawing text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to do this.

`#mybutton.hover
{
    color:blue;
}`

where id of the button is mybutton.